# JVM Major Garbage Collections Not Running for months

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, heap-memory

My application garbage collector used to run a major frequently, maybe once a day. But it stopped working suddenly. Now it has reached to 90 % and I had to restart the application few times.
This is in a production environment and what I allowed to do is read the logs and see the JVM states via provided UI.

Another observation I made was for the last 3 months, 1st 2 months there was no minor garbage collections but a lot of majors. For the last month no major collections but many minor collections.

Comment: You consider your application “working” or “non working” depending on whether major garbage collection occurs? And 90% of what? Maximum memory? Then why did you have to restart your application when there were still 10% left?

Comment: post your vm options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps it never does a major collection because you are restarting the application before it gets a chance.

You should be getting many minor collections if the young space is a reasonable size.

If you were only getting major collections most likely your JVM wasn't tuned correctly.  I would try to remove as many GC tuning parameters as possible and only add each one if you know it helps. Having too many tuning parameters set is a good way to get strange behaviour.